# chromium edge how to set auto change to IE mode when visit the web site

Tags: microsoft-edge

I follow up this link (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/ie-mode-in-new-edge-browser/27136524-ce2f-40b0-bb22-ab1593f9e646) to enable ie mode, but how to change change to IE mode when visit the web site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, there is no way to configure the MS Edge Chromium browser to launch the IE mode automatically when the user opens a specific site.

Users have to launch the site normally and then they can go to Ellipsis(…) >> More Tools >> Show this page as Internet Explorer.

If you think that the MS Edge Chromium browser should have the feature to automatically change to the IE mode when a user opens any specific site then I suggest you try to provide your feedback to Microsoft from the MS Edge Chromium browser.